# Preciso de ajuda para preencher espaços criados com o for

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Estou com um projeto de biblioteca, onde crio uma prateleira com varias seções e essas seções por sua vez tem suas linhas ou colunas assim:
[prateleira](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SnTR.png)

ate ai tudo bem consigo criar as prateleiras utilizando 2 ciclos for:

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= $info_prateleira->prateleira_numero_secoes; $i++):?>
    <th class="text-center" style="border: 3px solid #000;font-weight: bold;font-size:15px;">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i>&nbsp;Seção&nbsp;<?php echo $i;?></th>        
<?php endfor;?>
                                  
</tr>
                                  
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= $info_prateleira->prateleira_numero_colunas; $i++):?>
                                      
<tr style="border: 3px solid #000;">
                                        
<?php for($a = 1; $a <= $info_prateleira->prateleira_numero_secoes; $a++):?>
                                          
<th style="border: 3px solid #000;color:#fff;cursor:crosshair;" class="text-center bg-success text-white">
                                            
<a data-bs-toggle="modal" class="btn-pratelira text-white"
                                                        
data-bs-target="#prateleira-<?php echo $info_prateleira->prateleira_id.$a.$i;?>" >
                                            
<span class="badge bg-light text-dark w-100">Repartimento - N°:&nbsp;<?php echo $i;?>
                                            
</span>
                                            
<br>
                                            
<div class="progress mt-1">
                                              
<div class="progress-bar bg-danger progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" 
                                              

aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%">25 de&nbsp;<?php echo $info_prateleira->prateleira_numero_livros_secao;?>&nbsp;
                                              
</div>
                                            
</div>
                                              
Espaço para Livro!</a>
                                          
</th>
```

o problema e como eu faria para popular essas prateleiras com livros cadastrado no banco de dados? na hora de criar um livro eu já defino em qual prateleira, seção e coluna ele vai ficar, agora como poderia mostrar dinamicamente os livros que contem em cada prateleira?

Comment: Já tentou fazer a query no banco usando joins + group by por exemplo.

Comment: *"como poderia mostrar dinamicamente os livros "* faça em query no banco e pegue os resultados pra exibir os dados. Se não sabe como fazer isso, faça uma pesquisa, aqui no site muitas perguntas relacionadas, especialmente com `php` e `pdo`

Answer (score -3):

Eu conseguir preencher as secoes e linhas de acordo com a secao e linha que coloco na hora de cadastrar o livros, fiz da seguinte forma, criei 3 ciclos for 1 deles cria as tabelas o outro cria as colunas e o outro as linha, fiz um get_all no banco de dados trazendo todos os livros , depois disso fiz um foreach dentro dos for pra pegar as informações como objetos e exibir o titulo do livro, e ai dentro do foreach fiz uma condicional onde eu pego o contrador de todos os foreachs e faço uma comparação com os dados vindo do banco de dados, por exemplo
contador da tabela : $tabela_counter == id_tabela vindo banco
contador da linha : $linha_counter == numero_de_linhas vindo do banco
contador de secoes: $secoes_counter == numro_de_secoes vindo do banco

logo ele vai imprimir o livro pra min na seção em que os contadores forem iguais aos dados vindo do banco de dados, e pimba funcionou !

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).